# Rendered view requires blank line before (and after) tables, but preview works regardless

Tags: bug, status-review, markdown, markdown-rendering, tables

I saw a wrong table layout where the poster did the following and it looked wrong:

Table x
| Name  | Category |
| ----  | -------- |
| A     | High     |
| b     | Medium   |
| c     | Low      |

Adding an extra empty line below 'Table x' seemed to solve the layout problem (as done below).

Table x

| Name | Category |
| --- | --- |
| A | High |
| b | Medium |
| c | Low |

Interestingly, the 'preview' is shown correct in both cases... Click <kbd>Edit</kbd> on this post to see the difference.

Comment: cross-site dupe (MSE): [Markdown preview doesn't match post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358999/markdown-preview-doesnt-match-post) and [Markdown table preview does not detect missing blank line before table header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359192/markdown-table-preview-does-not-detect-missing-blank-line-before-table-header)

Comment: [Markdown preview doesn't match post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358999/markdown-preview-doesnt-match-post) is about a line break after the table, this is about before the table (like the second link @rene posted)

Comment: this is anoying, that the prevoew doesn't match the live view

Comment: How is this *still* not fixed...

Comment: The bug persists. I met him today on a question from a new member.

Comment: Yet another instance of this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30423554 (the table's formatting is broken in the post and in the edit review queue, but when editing the post, the preview shows the table correctly formatted)

Comment: This bug survived until 2022! Happy New Year.

Comment: Still there in 2023..

Comment: As some may celebrate it surviving into 2023, there is a new [cross-site dupe on CR](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10846/120114).