# Why does a table on Stack Overflow have a difference in the table's perspective when editing/asking question and in an actual question?

Tags: discussion, markdown, tables

I have been trying to create a table in a Stack Overflow question and am struggling to get my table right.

Here's the perspective in the Edit view,

[image]

However, when I hit <kbd>Post Question</kbd>, the table is messed up.

[image]

I have been looking at the [Markdown plugin](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-), but I can't spot what's wrong.

Here's my table:

| header |  |  |  | h2 | h2 | h2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tcp | 0 | 0 | XXX.XXX.XXX.host1:51000 | 0.0.0.0:* | LISTEN | off (0.00/0/0) |
| tcp | 0 | 0 | XXX.XXX.XXX.host1:59856 | XXX.XXX.XXX.host2:51000 | ESTABLISHED | off (0.00/0/0) |
| tcp | 0 | 0 | XXX.XXX.XXX.host1:51000 | XXX.XXX.XXX.host2:20352 | ESTABLISHED | keepalive (6007.95/0/0) |

PS: I can see a similar difference in this question as well

Comment: Already reported: [Rendered view requires blank line before tables, but preview accepts both](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404376/4642212).

Comment: What do you mean by *"perspective"* (in that context)? It is also used in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, so it turns out there's a *bug*. In the Edit view, the (2) `new line` is not mandatory to have a proper perspective of the table, but in the actual question it isn't.