# Embedded table is not showing correctly in question

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering, tables

I am trying to added a couple of embedded tables in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71599650/bigquery-unnest-query-optimisation-for-singular-record) using Stack Overflow's suggested format.

When I or another user open the edit window, the table presents correctly in the question preview. However, when posted it returns back to its input state.

Comment: `(48000 rows)` is **not** in the table, that breaks it

Comment: @jonrsharpe Good spot thankyou. Still the preview should exactly match the posted answer, should it not?

Comment: You would hope! See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404376/3001761.

Comment: It's a WYSIMOLWYG implementation. Like most if not all are.

Comment: [Bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359192/markdown-table-preview-does-not-detect-missing-blank-line-before-table-header) on [meta.se] too. There are multiple issues with the implementation of markdown tables on the  sites; none have been addressed as far as I am aware. This one is the probably the most common and most annoying; the fact that for many the preview window actively misleads the user really doesn't help.