# Table rendering currently broken in Stack Overflow previews

Tags: bug, editor, tables

Currently, when I add a table to a question or answer in Stack Overflow, it is not being rendered properly in previews.  It appears to currently work on other sites in the Stack Exchange network, as well as on Meta Stack Overflow.

### Example

```markdown
|id|name |email|
|--| --- | --- |
|1 | Sta |sta@example.com|
|2 |Danny|dany@example.com|
|3 |Elle |elle@example.com|
```

#### Current Stack Overflow rendering image

> [image: Screenshot of Stack Overflow showing incorrect rendering]

#### Current Meta Stack Overflow rendering image

> [image: Screenshot of Meta Stack Overflow showing correct rendering]

#### Live rendering (Meta Stack Overflow)

> | id | name | email |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Sta | sta@example.com |
> | 2 | Danny | dany@example.com |
> | 3 | Elle | elle@example.com |

Comment: Related, but reversed issue: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404376/6296561 (tables render in preview when they shouldn't be). Hasn't received an update, but wouldn't surprise me if they fixed it and broke it in the opposite direction instead. Assuming this wasn't also a problem to begin with anyway