# Markdown table works in preview but not when I post the content

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering, tables

I wrote a question using a Markdown table without an empty line between the previous paragraph and the table. It showed correctly in the preview and when I clicked "Review your question", but when I posted the question, it showed the text rather than the rendered table.

Like this:
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys                        | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra                              |
| -- | ----------- | ----- | ---------- | ----- | ------------------------------------ | -------------------- | ------- | ---- | -------- | -------- | ---------------------------------- |
| 1  | PRIMARY     | t0    | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                                 | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL | 10402901 | 100      | Using where                        |
| 3  | SUBQUERY    | c     | NULL       | range | PRIMARY,organisation_created         | organisation_created | 41      | NULL | 1        | 100      | Using where; Using index           |
| 2  | SUBQUERY    | u     | NULL       | range | PRIMARY,updated,organisation_created | updated              | 5       | NULL | 4        | 1.87     | Using index condition; Using where |

[image: Preview page showing correctly]

Comment: I can make it work correctly by adding a new line after "Like this:"

Comment: You need to add empty lines before and after the table for it to render correctly in an actual post.

Comment: I think this should have been closed as a duplicate of the [main report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404376/6083675).